# Composer and minimum-stability setting

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm trying to install a package from my gitlab account. My project composer.json is

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "http://myserver.com/myusername/mypackage.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "myusername/mypackage": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Running `composer install` gives me `A typo in the package name` or `The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting`. My minimum stability is `dev`, how can I have it lower than that? I'm pretty sure I don't have typos in package name: `git pull` works fine for this repository url.

Answer (score 0):

My bad: I missed the name property in the package I was trying to install. It was not "myusername/mypackage" so it was indeed a typo in the package name.